# What's the difference between python-minimal and python-all?

Tags: programming, python, package-management

Basically the question. I need to setup an environment that supports tkinter programming in python and maybe some network socket stuff too. I'd also like to emphasize that I need python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`python-all`, according to [the docs](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-all), is a minimal package intended to avoid hard-coded dependencies on python versions.

The two packages you would be looking for are probably [`python`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python) vs. [`python-minimal`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-minimal).  Between those two, the difference is pretty minimal.  For the most part, start tinkering with what is installed.  You'll probably find that everything is there.  If it isn't, look for a package or use `easy_install`.

Comment: Thanks, Eric.  I updated the links to point at an LTS release.

Comment: When the diff is minimal, why would you need both python and python-minimal? I use Ubuntu and the installer even wants libpython3.7-minimal.

Answer (score 0):

According the ubuntu xenial library of python minimal it refers as follows
python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.11-1~)
Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
python
interactive high-level object-oriented language (default version)

so by default if you got an installation that will be the python